# How to create normal non-state variables with a lifetime of the component in function-based react components?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building a component that renders 3d animation so in the processes, I have some heavy-in-size variables that need to be declared by the time the component is mounted and destructed by the time it's unmounted. (So I can not simply declare the variable inside the function component body because it will be destructed and re-created in every re-render) And for each separate instance of the component, there has to be a separate instance of these variables (So I can not declare them on the global scope of the module file)

I can declare it as a state variable but it's not a good approach performance-wise because it takes more resources than needed while no components need to subscribe to these variables.

In a class-based component, these variables would be defined as in the following pseudo-code:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  myHeavyVariable = getMyHeavyVariable();
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // setup my myHeavyVariable
  }
  ...
  render() {
    // use myHeavyVariable before rendering
    ...
  }
}
```

But how can we do that in function-based react components?

Comment: Use refs for variables that don't need to rerender the component

Comment: Are we talking about the useRef react hook or something else?

Comment: You are using class components so you will use `this.refs`

Comment: No no, I meant that that's how I would do it if I'm using class components. But I need to do it using function components. So what would be the equivalent when using function components?

Comment: Yes, `useRef` is used in function components

Comment: But I thought it's to get a reference for an element in the DOM, not to declare variables :?

Comment: You can declare variables as well https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useRef

Comment: I don't get why you say you can't declare it inside a hook's (which I assume is `useEffect`) body, Why should it get destructed/recreated on every re-render if you put it inside a `useEffect` with no dependencies?

Comment: Thank you so much, This pretty much solved my problem.  And yeah I edited my question, I meant inside the component itself